# Probability of a man being guilty based on 2 witnesses

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

We just had a massive trial with two witnesses: A and B. They both have a long history of not being fully accurate. A has a probability of $\frac{13}{14}$ of telling the truth and B has a probability of $\frac{14}{15}$ of telling the truth. Both A and B stated that convict C was guilty! We know that statistically, C is guilty with probability $\frac{1}{300}$. What is the probability that C is actually guilty? (We can assume that A and B telling the truth are independent events.)

I know that this is an example of Bayes' Theorem. But when I apply the theorem don't the numerator and denominator cancel out leaving $\frac{1}{300}$ as the answer. It seems that I am a bit confused with what exactly we need to calculate. Could someone please clarify mathematically what is asked in the question in reference to the theorem.

Thanks

Edit: My working

Given $P$(guilty)$= \frac{1}{300}$

We need to find $P$(guilty| both stated guilty). This is given by

$\frac{P(both stated guilty| guilty)P(guilty)}{P(both stated guilty)}$ from Bayes' Theorem. At this point, I think the conditional term in the numerator and the denominator are the same and all that remains is $P$(guilty)$= \frac{1}{300}$. I am obviously missing something but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Bayes' theorem is a good idea, but the result shouldn't be $1/300$. If you show your work, we can tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I have added an edit. Do look into it

Comment: What makes you think those two terms have the same value? Did you compute both of them? Note that the two witnesses speak the truth *most* of the time, so there definitely should be a difference between whether or not the defendant is guilty or not.

Comment: @MeesdeVries could you please post a detailed explanation. I am not really sure how to proceed from here. Thank you

Comment: Let $A_G, B_G, C_G$ be the events that $A$ and $B$ say guilty and $C$ is guilty respectively, and $C_I$ be the event that $C$ is innocent. Then $$P(A_G, B_G | C_G) = P(A_G | C_G)P(B_G | C_G)$$ and $$P(A_G, B_G | C_I) = P(A_G | C_I)P(B_G | C_I)$$since the events are independent. While $$P(A_G, B_G) = P(A_G, B_G | C_G)P(C_G) + P(A_G, B_G | C_I)P(C_I)$$ since $C_G$ and $C_I$ are exhaustive and mutually exclusive.